# Verifying Javascript integrity with Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, security, firefox-addon

I am working on an environment that relies on unedited scripts. All the basics are covered (secured location, https ...), but I'd like to add an additional check by verifying the scripts (calculating a checksum) in the users browser via a Firefox extension.

How would an extension be able to access the source of a loaded script? As I am fairly new to developing Firefox extensions, any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok. Lazy mode off. Developed an xpi that uses the tabs sdk to get the documents.scripts, downloaded the scripts and verified the hashes. Nobody should be able to slip a modified script under my belly now (at least .. not that easy).

Comment: can you share your solution below please so we can learn from ti